# Datadog get logs without facet

Tags: logging, datadog

I want to get logs that don't have a specific facet (half of my logs have some `@facet` but I want the other half)

I tried `-@facet`, `@facet:""` and `NOT @facet`  but doesn't work and google doesn't help

Feels like there is an easy way for doing this, halp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, apparently you can `-@facet:*` to exclude everything with a facet value

Didn't specify it in my question because it was not important, but what I really needed was a way to either **filter by a specific facet value, or get logs without said facet** such as:

```
(logs without the facet) || (logs with specific facet value)
```

The following works for me:

```
@facet:specificvalue OR -@facet:*
```

Comment: `-@facet:* OR -@facet:<specificvalue>`

prefixing operator - is mandatory to force the exclusion of values containing a given facet

Comment: yup, but thats not what I wanted. I've edited both the question and answer to hopefully be clearer